# How can I specify the frequency or breaks in scale_x_discrete in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

My dataset is such:

```
structure(list(Nacional = c("Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", 
"Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", "Nacional", 
"Nacional"), CCAA = c("09 Cataluña", "09 Cataluña", "09 Cataluña", 
"09 Cataluña", "09 Cataluña", "09 Cataluña", "09 Cataluña", 
"09 Cataluña", "09 Cataluña", "09 Cataluña"), Habitatge = c("General", 
"General", "General", "General", "General", "General", "General", 
"General", "General", "General"), Unitat = c("Variació anual", 
"Variació anual", "Variació anual", "Variació anual", "Variació anual", 
"Variació anual", "Variació anual", "Variació anual", "Variació anual", 
"Variació anual"), Data = c("2022T4", "2022T3", "2022T2", "2022T1", 
"2021T4", "2021T3", "2021T2", "2021T1", "2020T4", "2020T3"), 
    Total = c(5.5, 8.1, 7.2, 7.7, 6.1, 3.3, 3.2, 1.2, 1, 1.7)), row.names = 7041:7050, class = "data.frame")
```

And I want to plot it:

```
ggplot(subset(var_ine_habitatge, Data>"2008T1"))+  
  geom_line (aes(x=Data, y=Total, color= Habitatge, group=Habitatge), linewidth=0.7) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits=as.numeric(c(-20,14)), breaks=seq(from=-20, to=14, by=2)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0), seq(by=5))
```

But I do not want every label I have in `Data` which is the x axis. I want `Data` to appear in the x axis every 4 values, for instance. I have tried with breaks but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use a lambda function to only add a break for each fourth category. Note however, that doing so, you also lose the grid lines. As a second option you could use a lambda function and an `ifelse` to keep only the labels for each fourth category.

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(subset(var_ine_habitatge, Data > "2008T1")) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Data, y = Total, color = Habitatge, group = Habitatge), linewidth = 0.7) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = as.numeric(c(-20, 14)), breaks = seq(from = -20, to = 14, by = 2)) 

p +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = ~ .x[seq(1, length(.x), 4)])
```

[image]

```r
p +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0), labels = ~ ifelse(seq_along(.x) %% 4 == 1, .x, ""))
```

[image]