# Creating interval categorical variable and plot it continuously in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a dataset including 3 columns: firm, age, investment_return. I will need to get mean level of returns for different age groups of firms.
I use cut function to create categorical interval variable age_int

```
age_int = cut(df$age, break = 30)
```

Then I can compute the average return for each age-group of firms. But when I plot this average return as y, the X-axis are a bunch of overlapping age intervals with parentheses.

```
ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(age_int), av_return)) + 
  geom_point()
```

How can I plot this with the x-axis as normal continuous variable of age?

Answer (score 1):

One option to achieve your desired result without using `cut` to manually bin your `age` variable would be to use `scale_x_binned` for the binning and `stat_summary` to compute the mean returns per bin. For comparison I added a `geom_point` with the raw return.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  age = sample(1:50, 200, replace = TRUE),
  av_return = rnorm(200)
)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(age, av_return)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = .5) +
  stat_summary(geom = "point", fun = mean, color = "red", size = 3) +
  scale_x_binned(n.breaks = 30)
```

[image]

**EDIT** When you x axis gets too crowded then one option would be to remove some of the labels, e.g. adapting my answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75753892/how-can-i-specify-the-frequency-or-breaks-in-scale-x-discrete-in-ggplot/75754772#75754772) to your case the following code will add a label to each fifth tick or break only:

```r
p <- ggplot(df, aes(age, av_return)) +
  geom_point(alpha = .5) +
  stat_summary(
    geom = "point", fun = mean,
    color = "red", size = 3
  ) 

p +
  scale_x_binned(
    n.breaks = 30,
    labels = ~ ifelse(seq_along(.x) %% 5 == 1, .x, "")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if I can have just 30 dots of mean values in the graph but with less bins on the x-aixs? When I set breaks as 30, the x-axis looks bad since there are numbers overlapping and blocking each other in my case. Would it be possible to show like 10 bins on the x-axis but still with 30 mean values on the graph?

Comment: Don't think that this could be achievd with `scale_x_binned`. But see my edit for an approach which simply removes some of the labels to fix the issue of an crowded x axis.

Answer (score 0):

If you define 30 breaks, `cut` will break into bins with similar range.

```
cut(x, breaks=30)
# [1] (38.5,39.5] (32,32.9]   (46.9,47.9] (53.5,54.4] (45.1,46]  
# [6] (42.3,43.2] (57.2,58.1] (58.1,59.1] (59.1,60]   (57.2,58.1]
# 30 Levels: (32,32.9] (32.9,33.9] (33.9,34.8] ... (59.1,60]
```

You can try a `seq`ence incrementing `by=` say `5` years to get them more appropriate. Important is to add `0` and `Inf`.

```
cut(x, breaks=c(0, seq.int(from=15, to=70, by=5), Inf))
# [1] (35,40] (30,35] (45,50] (50,55] (45,50] (40,45] (55,60] (55,60]
# [9] (55,60] (55,60]
# 13 Levels: (0,15] (15,20] (20,25] (25,30] (30,35] (35,40] ... (70,Inf]
```

Not sure, what you mean by "as normal continuous variable", though.

---

*Data:*

```
x <- c(39, 32, 47, 54, 46, 43, 58, 59, 60, 58)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you need to plot mean level of a continuous variable, so clearly `geom_bar()` or `geom_col()` should be better than `geom_point()`. And since `ggplot2` is used, so `dplyr` as also a useful tool from TidyVerse should be comfortable for you to use.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data1 <- 
  tibble(
    age = 1:100,
    av_return = age * 10,
    age_int = cut(age, breaks = 30)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(age_int) %>% 
  summarise(
    mean_av = mean(av_return)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Data for testing, this is basicly what you did. And my advice is to change the label on ggplot2 like this:

```
ggplot(data1, aes(age_int, mean_av)) + 
  geom_col() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 1)
  )
```

Picture like this:

[image]

Also the `cut()` function has a `labels` argument in it, maybe you want to give it a try.

Or use `stat_summary` together with `scale_x_binned()` like this. This is `dplyr`-free by the way.

```
data2 <- data.frame(age = 1:100)
data2$av_return <- data2$age * 10
ggplot(data2, aes(age, av_return)) +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "bar") +
  scale_x_binned(n.breaks = 30)
```

[image]